# regex javascript: start at * and end at \n(?!\*) and ignore If any * in the middle

Tags: regex

I wanted to get every thing between first occurence of (*) and (\n)

**Here is the string:**

***Set of classes with distinct  scalable between plugs, cores, and logs and are  with and test data.*Maps of class distributions across the basin.*Description of the origin of the various classes and their link to types.**\nTesting Start
***Test New*Test New**\nOneMore list
***Set of classes with distinct  scalable between plugs, cores, and logs and are  with and test data.*Maps of class distributions across the basin.*Description of the origin of the various classes and their link to types.types.**\nend

Text in bold is what I need to get.

Comment: That regex is rather trivial, and you seem to have most of it already. Do you know about lazy [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and that `[\s\S]` matches any character, including linebreaks, in JavaScript?

Comment: \*.*\n(?!\*)
I tried this expression. But It only matching the last line of the each set.
For example:
*Set of classes with distinct  scalable between plugs, cores, and logs and are  with and test data.
*Maps of class distributions across the basin.
*Description of the origin of the various classes and their link to types.                                                                      
Result:
*Description of the origin of the various classes and their link to types.

Comment: I don't know how anybody can answer this unclear question, let alone it being accepted. Its totally ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
result = subject.match(/\*[\s\S]*?\n(?!\*)/g);
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/tW3tW1/1).

Answer (score 0):

Alternate, possibly quicker regex.

```
/\*[^\r\n]*\r?\n(?!\*)/g
```